# Joomla Json UTF8

Tags: php, joomla

my view.html.php

```
class LigaportalViewJsonarticles extends JViewLegacy
{
    /**
     * Display the view
     */
     public function display($tpl = null)
    {
    // Get the document object.
    $document = JFactory::getDocument(); 
    $document->setMimeEncoding('application/json');
    JRequest::setVar('tmpl', 'component');   
    $ligaId = JRequest::getVar("competitionID",null,"get","String");
    $limit = JRequest::getVar("limit",null,"get","String");
    $model = $this->getModel();
    $data = $model->getContent($ligaId, $limit*5);
   //  parent::display($tpl);  
    //Deaktivierung der gesamten Layout-Komponente, 
    //die für html, head, meta und body-Tags zuständig ist
 //echo  utf8_encode($data);
    parent::display($tpl);


    echo new JResponseJson( $data);
    jexit();;
}//function 
}
```

Now my problem is the output , there are \u00d6 in it. the $data is a simple joomla select.

my output is this:

```
{"success":true,"message":null,"messages":null,"data":    [{"ligaid":"33","title":"Transfernews in der O\u00d6-Liga - nun auch Champions League-Glanz in Bad Ischl","publish_up":"2014-01-30 18:50:20"},{"ligaid":"33","title":"SV Gmundner Milch holt 4 Talente","publish_up":"2014-01-30 12:56:02"},{"ligaid":"33","title":"SC Marchtrenk zieht zweite Verst\u00e4rkung an Land","publish_up":"2014-01-28 09:53:51"},{"ligaid":"33","title":"O\u00d6-Ligisten im Testspieleinsatz","publish_up":"2014-01-26 18:21:38"},{"ligaid":"33","title":"UFC Eferding: Keine Transfers, aber intensive Vorbereitung","publish_up":"2014-01-26 09:01:27"}]}
```

thx

Comment: Why is that a problem?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is basically with `JResponseJson` is that it is using `json_encode()`. When you don't pass any extra parameters to it, `json_encode()` will automatically have this behavior.

To get this to work **you need PHP 5.4+** and to pass to `json_encode()` the option `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`. See also the page with [Predefined JSON Constants](https://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php)

To get back to your issue, replace the line in question with:

```
 echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Hope this helps.